# How to push and pull separate projects in a single repository?

Tags: git, github

I want to know how to work with multiple projects in a single GitHub repository.

Suppose, I want to put my all office projects in a single repository with the name of Office. All of my future projects will be placed here separately with separate project name.

How can I achieve these. Thank you

Comment: Use a separate branch for every project, the name of each project as the name of its branch?

Comment: Folders? Or git submodules? What are your constraints and what have you tried?

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea. But maybe it isn't. What's the reason you want to avoid using different git repositories for different projects? Maybe you have a good reason, but I can't really think of one.

Comment: And yes, you can have multiple unrelated roots with their own sets of branches in the same repository. Its rarely done and has various problems (for example that they share a namespace for branches/tags/...), but it's possible.